# VAWP link breaks intermittently with 'System is temporarily Unavailable'

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

I've been testing the capture and persistence of the exact copy of the email sent in a custom DE, have referenced these posts (there are many other similar posts):

1. [Building a custom VAWP page for emails](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252851/building-a-custom-vawp-page-for-emails?newreg=eb10fe875719491cbc99804b3164e1a1) which references
2. https://webep.fr/feed-a-send-log-send-history-data-extension-automatically/

I am using the AMPScript code to do a InsertDE with the relevant fields including unique keys and the email content (using HTTPGet). But there are intermittent issues with the HTTPGet (roughly about 8% of the cases 7/87) where the following was returned in the HTTPGet

'The System is temporarily unavailable. We apologize.....Please try again later.'

Of course, this cannot be retried 'later'. And for the same reasons as in the referenced links, we do not want to use the Sendlog DE, rather use a customDE.

Is there a known solution/workaround for this issue?

Also, is there a similar solution to capture SMS sends?

Thanks
Sam

Comment: Is it a Triggered Send or a UI Send? For the 7/87 cases where it worked, do you remember if the working ones were the first record in your audience?

Comment: Hi Eduardo, these were Triggered Sends. And it worked 80 out of 87  cases, 7 cases did not work. These are triggered via an API and not part of a campaign and the 7 cases were random. 

Interesting this stopped occurring after '3/30/2023 11:57:13 PM' (UTC-6) and there have been a further 82 emails since triggered and this issue is not seen

Comment: That's promising. My next suggestion then would be to try using the catch {} function to find the issue, then build a workaround for it. Check this post out: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/08/09/debugging-ampscript/

Comment: Hi @EduardoArias I am unable to reproduce the issue. There have been over 5000 emails captured and no failure since the time I reported in my earlier comment. The one plausible explanation could be that we applied retention policy (7 days) on the Sendlog DE which had over 4m rows and cleared the existing data (it was only being used for testing) and that housekeeping was done around the time this issue appears to have stopped. Cheers Sam